# translating django template code in python 2 to 3

Tags: python, django

Hello please am trying to implement an archive of blog post in a test website am designing for learning purpose. Please am very new to python and am still trying to cut my teeth. I saw a very good tutorial on how to implement archive of events on this site https://unweb.me/blog/monthly-archives-on-Django i understand the code on the view. My only problem is implementing the code on the template side. I have tried everything but it seems not to be working. My guess is that the tutorial was written using python 2 while am learning python 3. Below is the code in the template.

```
  {% for event_year in list_events %}
    <ul class="year">{{event_year.keys.0}}
        {% for month, events in event_year.values.0.items %}
            <!--show only months with events! -->
            {% if events %} 
                <li id="{{event_year.keys.0}}-{{month}}" class="month">
                    <div class="month-data">
                        <div class="collapsed">►&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="expanded" style="display:none;">▼&nbsp;</div>
                        <span class="name">{{events.0.date|date:"F"}}</span>
                        <span class="counter"> ({{events|length}})</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="events" style="display:none;">
                    {% for event in events %}
                        <li class="event">
                        <a class="title" href="#">{{event.name}}</a>
                        <div class="date">{{event.date|date:"j M Y"}}</div>
                        <div class="place">{{event.place}}</div> 
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

The very part i don't understand is this main line {{event_year.keys.0}} please any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? Which line is not getting displayed?

Comment: @Rahul Gupta It displays nothing even though there are events in the list. I believe it has to do with me using python 3. The tutorial was written for python 2

Comment: Please check if you are passing `list_events` in the context and that `list_events` is not empty.

Comment: yes list_events returns a list of dictionary